# Layout for displaying text and buttons next to a picture

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to acomplish something like this:
[image]

And so far after hours of learning bootstrap and playing with the grid system I managed to do this:

[image]

Code that I use:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUxMDc1OTAzM15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTMwOTMyMDI@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,674,1000_AL_.jpg" style="width: 130px; height: 200px">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="text-title">Logan 2017</div>
                <p>
                  Set in the future, Logan and Professor Charles Xavier must cope with the loss of the X-Men when a corporation lead by Nathaniel Essex is bent on destroying the world. With Logan's healing ...
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-bold-text">IMDb</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I want to be able to maximize the picture to the size of the panel, make buttons stick to bottom and fix the margin of the text.

Can someone help me ? Thanks!

I don't need anyone to do the code for me, just tell me what should I be looking for. Is there any spacing between columns in bootstrap ? I tried playing with margins and paddings but no chance of acomplishing what I want.

Comment: you haven't added the boostrap files inside your code snippet so it isn't rendering properly

Comment: my bad, I added it now

Comment: You should use the smallest column designation possible. For example if on all screens it should be 6 columns wide, use `col-xs-6`. If it's 12 on mobile and 6 on larger you would do both `col-xs-12 col-md-6`. If you only specify a `md` size, the browser won't know what to do smaller than that. Also, rows need to have columns as children.

Comment: Are you opposed to flexbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/0jv537r0/1/

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="well" style="position: relative; background: #fff;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUxMDc1OTAzM15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTMwOTMyMDI@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,674,1000_AL_.jpg">
          </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
         <div class="text-title">Logan 2017</div>
         <p>
         Set in the future, Logan and Professor Charles Xavier must cope with the loss of the X-Men when a corporation lead by Nathaniel Essex is bent on destroying the world. With Logan's healing ...
         </p>
         </div>
         </div>
         <button class="btn btn-warning btn-bold-text" style="position: absolute; bottom: 20px; left: 33.33333333%;">IMDb</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" style="position: absolute; bottom: 20px; right: 20px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, I changed it to a well instead of a panel since you wern't actually using any of the panel elements other than the border. My answer isn't 100% full proof, you'd want to bring the styles not inline and add specifics for different screen widths, but in a nutshell at least you can see what I did to accomplish your goal. You could also use flexbox and then keep the buttons inside the `col-xs-8` because with felxbox you could make the height of the `col-xs-8` element match the height of the image.

Your "problem" is a commong one. Placing elements at the bottom of a parent element. There is generally not an out of the box solution to accomplish this. You must use position absolute. This position elements based on their closest **non static** parent. You could do this on the `col-xs-8` element but because it's height won't match that of the image, that won't work you need to move the buttons outside the column. (Columns by default in Bootstrap have a non static position).

Now there are countless ways to accomplish what you wanted I just chose the route closet to what you had. I might suggest the `media` object (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media) native to bootstrap. Wrap the media element in a wrapper with a border and you should be close to what you want, but really, media, panel, wells they are all similar. That is why in Bootstrap 4 they have all been removed in favor of cards. You might be better off going with BS4 as well. It's getting closer and closer to release and I have a site fully done with the current alpha and it's pretty solid. We're about to push the project to production too.

Comment: Awesome! I made some tweaks to your code and I acomplished what I wanted. I will also take a look at BS4. Thank you :)